# Problem with printing in a .rdlc local processing exception

Tags: c#, ado.net, reporting, rdlc

I want to print my report without showing the report viewer.

I'm using this code:

```
DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();
d.CONNECTER();

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("exec  lastorder ", d.cnx);
da.Fill(ds1, "lastorder");

SqlDataAdapter da1 = new SqlDataAdapter("exec  cafepp", d.cnx);
da1.Fill(ds1, "cafeapp");

d.DECONNECTER();

LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
report.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Report1.rdlc";
report.EnableHyperlinks = true;
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("lastorder", ds1.Tables["lastorder"]));
report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("cafeapp", ds1.Tables["cafeapp"]));

report.Refresh();
report.PrintToPrinter();
```

The error is:

> Local processing exception was unhandled

I'm using [this class](https://gist.github.com/shakee93/f5eb53a1dfec486e1376d63c3063e51b).

and I get the error in this line:

```
  report.Render("Image", deviceInfo, CreateStream,
           out warnings);
```

What can I try?

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to wrong initialisation of the printer.
Please try to follow suggestions from this page :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms252091(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN